# Can the console stop rolling up when sending cat or print?

Tags: r

Is it possible to cat or print specific message at same place without keeping scolling up?

```
A <- proc.time()[3]

for (i in 1:1e3) {
  B <- proc.time()[3]
  system("sleep, 60")

  Time_Mark <- round(B - A, 2)
  cat(paste("time passed", Time_Mark, "\n"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing `\n` with `\r` and see if that does it. The reason it *might* work is that `\r` is a pure carriage return (without going to a new line) and depending on your system it will be interpreted as such. Slightly more info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return